# Run `devtools::document()` before installing

Tags: r, github, installation, package, devtools

I've just pushed a package on [Github](https://github.com/iago-lito/bimark), which I regularly document, test and install on my machine with the following R commands:

```
library(devtools)
library(testthat)
setwd("bimark")
document()     # cheers to roxygen2!
use_testthat() # cheers to testthat!
setwd("..")
install("bimark", build_vignettes=TRUE) # cheers to R-markdown!
library(bimark)
test_package("bimark")
run_examples("bimark")
```

However, installing it from github with:

```
install_github("iago-lito/bimark")
```

does not work since

```
ERROR: a 'NAMESPACE' file is required
```

The reason why I do not version my `NAMESPACE` file is that it is automatically generated by `devtools::document()`.

How can I make the full doc-test-installation easy for my users without versionning non-source files such as `NAMESPACE`?

Comment: NAMESPACE is autogenerated only if devtools::document() and roxygen2 is used. Otherwise, you create it by hand. Therefore, I think they consider it as a source file which needs to be versioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NAMESPACE is autogenerated only if devtools::document() and roxygen2 is used. Otherwise, you create it by hand. Therefore, I think they consider it as a source file which needs to be versioned.